# Document upload, indexing and advanced search tool

Tags: document-management, file-search, document-indexing, tags

We are currently looking for a tool that will be used in order to upload and index documents, extract or define metadata about these documents and perform advanced search (i.e. it must be able to support complex queries that will return all matching documents as a result).

The tool should necessarily fulfill the following requirements:

1. The advanced search functionality must be provided by point and click mechanisms and not by RegEx/custom queries/etc., since they are not user friendly
2. We should be able to set custom attributes/tags/keywords upon the upload of the documents, or the tool should be able to extract these keywords on its own. Then we must be able to use these keywords in order to search for documents.
3. It must be a web application (not desktop) which we can install and host on our servers.
4. *(Optional)* If possible, the tool should also provide some report generation functionality.

In case it helps, the tool that was closest to our requirements was `CKAN`, but we had to reject it since its search functionality was rather complex (no point-and-click mechanism).

We have googled for `open-data tools`, `reference management tools`, `archiving tools` and `indexing tools`, but none of them seems to exactly match what we need.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: This reminded me Store Manager for Woocommerce / Wordpress and JCE / Joomla.